# How to restart the game in SpriteKit and Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, restart, skscene

I'm new to Swift and SpriteKit, as I'm trying to make a game which is a sample one. Till the end scene I'm able to build correctly but when I attach the end scene to start scene, the game crashes and I have no idea. I have received 2 different types of errors like:

1. function signature specialization  of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2) and Theard 1: EXE - Breakpoint
2. ignoresilbingsorder: Unwrapped nil optionals.

**sample code:**

```
if nodeAtPoint(location) == playButton {
    var scene = playScene(size: self.size)
    var skView = self.view as SKView!
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    skView.presentScene(scene)
} - this is gamescene
```

**playscene:**

```
var scene = EndScene(size: self.size)
var skView = self.view as SKView!
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
skView.presentScene(scene)
```

**EndScene:**

```
Restartbtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width / 4, height: 80))
Restartbtn.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2.9, y: view.frame.size.height / 3.8)

Restartbtn.setTitle("Restart", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
Restartbtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
Restartbtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("Restart"), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view?.addSubview(Restartbtn)

Restart() {
self.view?.presentScene(playScene(), transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.0))
Restartbtn.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

whenever the hero collides the some hurdles the game should restart(in between i'm removing every spritenode, action and a lable even scene itself), in end scene we will present GameScene, even i have tried directly presenting the gamescene even then im facingsame problem.

Comment: Show your code for end scene.

Answer (score 0):

One way to restart the game is to reload the whole scene from scratch using a button or setting it to a function. Hope That helps. If show your code when you ask a question people will be able to help you more :)